# JDBC connection in Servlets

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to `MySQL` using `JDBC` connection in a `Servlet`.I'm using `Eclipse` and added the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar` in /WEB_INF/lib folder.

Also the same jar is also added into `Java Build Path`.After running the project I'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678) 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at com.shubh.Download.doGet(Download.java:42)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Although I've added the required jar in the classpath. Why is the `ClassNotFoundException` still generating ?
 [Here](http://pastebin.com/rkCASnLF) is my code.

Comment: I'm guessing that just dropping the jar on the WEB-INF/lib folder is not enough to make eclipse actually add it to the compiled version of your app, can you try putting your jar on a common dir (like the base of your workspace) and then right click your project->properties->java build path->add external jar, also try right click your server on the servers view and select "Clean" to be sure Eclipse is updating the build

Comment: Your code compiles ok for me. Been a while since I used Eclipse but I think you can look in .classpath to see if there is a classpathentry for the jar. See if you can export an ant build file which will tell you one way or another if the directory which contains the jar is in the compile classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, dropping `.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` should work. `eclipse` is smart enough to recognize files added in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Just to check you can look in `.classpath` file to see whether it contains an entry like
`<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar"/>`

But, It is advised not to hassle with `classpath` entry. Remove all unnecessary reference from Java Build Path and then clean and build again should work.